# Format Date Axis on Bar Chart R

Tags: r, datetime, graph, ggplot2, bar-chart

I need to format the X Axis to show year only spaced apart every 5 years.

Current Graph:

[image]

I have tried getting the d2$Date into a Character and converting with chron() and then using scales() but R continues to tell me the date format is still not correct.

Code:

```
d2 <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16400709/StackOverflow/Data_Outbreaks_Bar.csv")
head(d2,n=20)

Graph2 <-ggplot(d2, aes(x=d2$Date, y=d2$FujitaMiles)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
labs(x="Date", y="Magnitude")

Graph2
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: is `d2$Date` of class Date? Then `Graph2 + scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("5 years"), labels = date_format("%Y"))` should do it.